# jQuery mobile autocomplete is not updating itself

Tags: jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I'm new to jQuery and jQuery mobile.

I'm trying to get an autocomplete field working. What I have so far is pretty much ripped right from the demo at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview-autocomplete-remote/

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#foo", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class=\'ui-loader\'><span class=\'ui-icon ui-icon-loading\'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi/perl_script.pl",
            data: \'search=\' + value,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(val));
                html += "<li>Just a test</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
});
```

I have confirmed that json data is getting returned with the js alert. That's all working perferctly. If my perl script returns 3 json records, I get three alerts with the stringified JSON.

However, the records never get displayed by the widget even if I use a the simple "Just a test" string as shown here in my code as I try to debug the problem.

Here is the relevant html code:

```
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form class="ui-filterable">
      <input id="autocomplete-input" data-type="search" placeholder="Last name">
    </form>
  <ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-input="#autocomplete-input"></ul>
```

Comment: OK, if I throw an alert dialog up after this line

    `$ul.html( html );`

I can see the options pop up. When I dismiss the alert dialog, the options disappear, too.

Comment: I'm getting close. I put in actual values into the <li> element and it started working. No idea why.

However, I am not able to select any of the options. I just click and nothing happens.

Comment: OK, I learned I had to add an event handler for the widget to detect when it was changed.

Answer (score 0):

See comments to the original post for the answer.

Comment: don't refer, please add the content here.